# Error Installing sample datasets with QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis

Recently tried installing QGIS 3.4 on Windows 10 and somehow it always throws error while trying to install the sample training data sets.

While QGIS itself installed without issues, the data sets failed to load.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Can you please tell us, what data you want to install and what the installation process is? I, for myself, have never used or even seen installable data sets for qgis. You can download datasets like the alaska data set: https://qgis.org/downloads/data/qgis_sample_data.zip

Answer (score 2):

When you install QGIS (on Windows at least, not sure about other operating systems), the installation wizard gives you a list of selectable downloads. One option is the actual QGIS software. The other three are optional test/sample datasets. I assume this is the "installable data" you're talking about; if not, please clarify your question.

[image]

If this dataset fails to download when you install QGIS, you should take two steps:

1. [Make a bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues). Most QGIS users don't want the tutorial data, so it's not surprising that no one has noticed this bug before now.
2. Download the data from a different source. Hopefully it's one of the links below, although since I've never actually installed the test data I can't be 100% sure.

   - https://qgis.org/downloads/data/qgis_sample_data.zip (According to Andreas Müller's comment this should be the Alaska data set.)
   - https://qgis.org/downloads/data/ (Here you can download the files of the Alaska data set individually.)
   - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data/archive/v2.0.zip (This is the dataset used in the QGIS tutorial. I'm not sure if it's the same data as the sample datasets.)
   - https://grass.osgeo.org/download/sample-data/ (The Spearfish South Dakota and North Carolina datasets are available on this page.)

Comment: Yes I am referring to the sample dataset coming along with the installation of QGIS Software.

Comment: I tried installing multiple times but the same result, so I need to make a bug report.

Comment: Another issue that I am facing is that the default OpenStreetMap does not open/ not visible. Is this because of the missing dataset is something I wasn't sure of.

Comment: Thanks for the links to various sample data. Let me try to download the grass data and see if this resolves the issue